# How to indent only the second line of a paragraph?

Tags: indentation, paragraphs, polyglossia, hebrew

I am not an expert in Hebrew typesetting, but the majority of the works I study has the second line of each paragraph indented. Is there a package that would allow me to do this, or will this need to be programmed? I am rather new to TeX and I am looking to use this as an alternative to Word. Any help or direction to find the right info is appreciated.

Here is a sample of what I am doing (including the suggesion of using parshape):

```
%\documentclass[twocolumn]{book}%Compile with xelatex
\documentclass[]{article}%set up as article for example
\usepackage{polyglossia}
%\usepackage[margin=1in, paperwidth=6in, paperheight=9in]{geometry}
\setdefaultlanguage{hebrew}
\newfontfamily\hebrewfont{Narkisim}
\newlength\iiindent \setlength\iiindent{15pt} 
\newcommand\secindent{\parshape 3 0pt \linewidth 0pt\dimexpr\linewidth-\iiindent\relax 0pt \linewidth } 
\setlength\parindent{0pt}
\begin{document}
\everypar{\secindent}
ב פאית הזקן הם חבטה ורבו בהם הרעות לפיכך
ירא שמים יצא את כילמ ולא יעביר תער על
זקנו כלל ואפילו על שפה הﬠליונה או תחת הגרון:

ג ועל פאות הראש יש נ"כ לאו בתורה והוא מה
שכתוב לא תקיפו פאה ראשכם וי"א רפאוה הראש
אסור מן התורה אפילו כסםפרים כﬠין תﬠר דהיינו
 סמוך לבשרו. ושיפור המאה מסנני שזור שעל
פרחוני וצר לססה סן האוזן מקום שהלחי היוחתון
ייצא וםתפרר שם ובל רוחב סקופ וה לא הנזו בו
יד מצר שהוא אבבלל פאות הראש ומשם ולסםה
מהחלון פאה הזקן. ובﬠו"ה מצוי מוסﬠבירין את
חפאות [וביותר ﬠ"י רסאשינקﬠ שהוציא וויצה"ר
סויורש] ונר סבור לבשרן םמש ואין סשייזיין כלל ויש
בזה חשש דאורייתא ובנ"ל והיה להם לשייר עכ"פ
קצת סן הקונה וביותר מזה יש סרכחורימ שכונה
שהספר מםפר ראשו הוא מגלח לו השור שאצל אונו
לצר הפנים ור.וא סחסה שסוםﬠין שחושבין שפאה
חראש נקרא רק סה שאנו קורין פאה ולא בן הוא
באשר כתבנו והוא לאו נסיר ראורײתכיו לריית וגם
זה הלאו הוא אפילו על הניקף וﬠ"כ אפילו אם חסםםר
הוא ﬠבו"ם יש לישראל להזהירו שלא יגﬠ כי כלל
במסים ההיא ינם כםרחץ סוהר להפסיק את המספר
שלא ינלחבסקום ההיא אם יהיו רבריו נשסﬠין לו
וכמבואר כא"ח סימן פ"ר דכדי לאפרושי מאיסורא
סוהר אפילו כסרחץ ע"ש:

ד אתר המקיף פאת הראש ואחר הניק. יוניון הםשחיזיז
פאה הזקן או רגשיות תייבין אלא שהניקו כיון שאינו
ﬠושח סונטה אינו לוקה אא"כ ססה ראשו או זקנו
אליו להקיפו אבל איסורא איכא אזניים שאינו סםייﬠ
כלל לפיכך אסור להיות גיקף ובשתי אפילו ﬠ"י שו"ב
ואפילו אינו מסייﬠ כלל כגון שאינו ססה את ﬠצסי אליו
כלל. ופשום ראם הוא מקיף פאת ראשו או משחית
פאת זקנו ﬠ"י ישראל צובר צור ﬠני לאו ולפני יניר לא
החן מכשול שﬠלירו ﬠובר וזםנלרוו בלאוין דאורייתא
וכנ"ל. ופותר ישראל להקיף את פאת ראש חﬠו"נ
ולהשתית את פאת זקנו ביון שאינו םוזהר הﬠו:ג
בזה כלל:
\end{document}
```

Working code.

Comment: Umm, as a Hebrew speaker I'll say that I've never seen even _one_ text in Hebrew with the second line of paragraphs indented.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

To apply this to every paragraph, you can use `\parshape` and `\everypar`; the following example shows this approach; the indentation is controlled throught the `\iiindent` length (set in the example to `15pt`); since Hebrew is written right-to-left, the indentation is on the right:

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\newlength\iiindent
\setlength\iiindent{15pt}
\newcommand\secindent{%
  \parshape 3 0pt \linewidth 0pt\dimexpr\linewidth-\iiindent\relax 0pt \linewidth
}
\setlength\parindent{0pt}

\begin{document}
\everypar{\secindent}

\lipsum[1-3]

\end{document}
```

[image]

To apply this for only selected paragraphs, the use of `\everypar` is not required, and you can simply invoke `\secindent` before the selected paragraph.

In the exampe I used left-to-right text since I don't have the fonts used by **Menachem**.

Comment: Due to the scope of my project, I'm using polyglossia instead. Unfortunately with the solution you provided, the paragraphs are indenting on the left rather than the right.

Comment: @Menachem you need to use the second variant of `\parshape` that I mentioned at the end of my answer: `\newcommand\secindent{\parshape 3 0pt \linewidth 0pt\dimexpr\linewidth-\iiindent\relax 0pt \linewidth
}`.

Comment: @Menachem I updated my answer showing only the definition for indentation on the right.

Answer (score 2):

I have no any knowledge of Hebrew, but probably you are really looking for the  usual ragged left Hebrew format and not just a  second line indentation. Try with the `cjhebrew` package or simply the `\raggedleft` command.

[image: MWE]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{cjhebrew}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\begin{document}

\begin{cjhebrew}
b*:re’+siyt b*ArA’ ’E:lohiym ’et ha+s*Amayim w:’et hA’ArE.s; w:hA’ArE.s
hAy:tAh tohU wAbohU w:.ho+sEk: ‘al--p*:ney t:hOm w:rU/a.h ’E:lohiym
m:ra.hEpEt ‘al--p*:ney ham*Ayim;
\end{cjhebrew}

\bigskip

\raggedleft\lipsum[2]

\end{document}
```